# Netbeans 15 does not find some apps located in "/bin"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans, flatpak, netbeans-15

Netbeans 15 can't open firefox or node.js on Linux Mint 21 (Ubuntu 22).
It all boils down that it cannot see some apps located in /bin
If I go to Tools->General->Webrowser->Edit->Browse...

I cannot see **firefox** or **node** at the path  `/bin` with the internal Netbeans file browser, while if I use the system file explorer they are shown normally.

So it seems that somehow Netbeans has no access to these applications? Strangely other apps like /bin/gpg  or /bin/cp for example are shown correctly within the Netbeans file browser window (started with the browse button)

**UPDATE:**

It is working without problem on **Netbeans 12** which I just have installed on the same system. So only Netbeans 15 has the problem.

**UPDATE 2**

Netbeans 15 was installed via flatpak and and I suppose that the flatpak rights management does restrict access to firefox.

Comment: Flatpak is the problem here. Building from source is the only solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

Flatpak's right management / sand-boxing does restrict access to Firefox and other apps like node. If I build **Netbeans 15** from source, everything is working. Flatpak can be a real mess here. :(